# Extracting values from file

Tags: java, regex, string

I've got around 10 lines of data in a text file below containing the following

```
X-Value = -0.525108, Y-Value = 7.746691, Z-Value = 5.863008, Timestamp(milliseconds) = 23001
X-Value = -0.755030, Y-Value = 7.861651, Z-Value = 6.016289, Timestamp(milliseconds) = 23208
```

The code I have right now uses a BufferedReader reading every line of the file but what I really want to do is extract the  **X-Value**, **Y-Value**, **Z-Value** and **Timestamp(milliseconds)** values from each line.  Could this be done with using simple String methods such as substring or would this suit the use of regular expressions?

Comment: I think split() is good enough.

Comment: Would you care to explain why using split in this scenario is a poor decision?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first split the strings by `,`s, then split each part by `=`, then trim leading/trailing spaces as necessary.

You can use `String.split()` or `java.util.StringTokenizer` for this.

Comment: I think split is the worst way to go here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.split` to split your string on `,` and `=`

```
String str = "X-Value = -0.525108, Y-Value = 7.746691, Z-Value = 5.863008, Timestamp(milliseconds) = 23001";
ArrayList<String> final_data = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] data = str.split(",");
for(String S : data)
final_data.add(S.trim().split("=")[1]);

for(String s : final_data)
System.out.println(s.trim());
```

Output =

> -0.525108
>
> 7.746691
>
> 5.863008
>
> 23001

Comment: Split is a very poor arbiture of validation style matching.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scanner like this to extract your values:

```
String str = "X-Value = -0.525108, Y-Value = 7.746691, Z-Value = 5.863008, Timestamp(milliseconds) = 23001";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str);
if (scanner.findInLine("^X-Value\\s*=\\s*([^,]*),\\s*Y-Value\\s*=\\s*([^,]*),\\s*Z-Value\\s*=\\s*([^,]*),\\s*Timestamp\\(milliseconds\\)\\s+=\\s+([^,]*)\\s*$") != null) {
    MatchResult result = scanner.match();
    System.out.printf("x=[%s]; y=[%s]; z=[%s]; ts=[%s]%n", result.group(1), result.group(2), result.group(3), result.group(4));
}
scanner.close();
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
x=[-0.525108]; y=[7.746691]; z=[5.863008]; ts=[23001]
```

Comment: Its almost the same as split, with all the pitfalls, except it more specific, but just as bad.

Answer (score 0):

Why play around with split(), just go for a regex!

`X-Value\s*=\s*([\d.+-]*).*Y-Value([\d.+-]*).*Z-Value\s*=\s*([\d.+-]*).*Timestamp\(milliseconds\)\s*=\s*(\d*)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s = "X-Value = -0.525108, Y-Value = 7.746691, Z-Value = 5.863008, Timestamp(milliseconds) = 23001";
    s = s.replaceAll(" ", "");
    String[] split = s.split("=|,");

    BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(split[1]);
    BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal(split[3]);
    BigDecimal z = new BigDecimal(split[5]);
    String ts = split[7];
```